# Ways to define a curve

Tags: collision-detection, bezier, continuous, physics-engine, elliptic-curve

**I'm trying to give shapes in my physics engine roundness/ curvature.**

I am aware of various methods for mathematically defining curves; such as bezier-cruves, ellipses, etc. However I am not sure which methods would be most appropriate for use in my physics engine, because speed, feasibility of construction, and flexibility of each method must be considered. I want a system in which a user can easily form fairly complex curves, but still make the intersection calculations simple and fast.

My physics engine is also purely continuous, which means I must be able to calculate the time in which curves will collide with other curves and lines based on a constant linear/angular velocity.

- **What techniques are there for mathematically defining a 2D curve?**
- **What are the advantages/disatvantages of each in terms of speed, flexibility, and  simplicity of construction?**
- **Is the technique feasible for an engine where predictability of shape intersection is crucial?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like your tag says, you are describing [Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). It is mathematically well defined, so you'd be able to use that for collision detection, although depending on what you're doing it might make the equations slightly harder to write and solve. I don't know much about it, but something that seems to be the standard way to approach splines is [NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NURBS), and wikipedia seems to have quite an article on the topic. The NURBS article probably covers all this, but a quick and dirty way to draw a smooth curve between a bunch of points is to use [cubic splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) by interpolating a cubic polynomial in between every two points such that the first derivatives match at the edges. That way you get a curve that goes through all your points and looks smooth everywhere, with no sharp corners at the initial points.